# For some reason I can't restart a script

Tags: node.js, docker, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io

It used to work fine on my docker stack, I could run a script several times, but lately, even a simple script like this

```
const webdriverio = require('webdriverio');
let options;
options = {
    desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },
    host: '192.168.99.100',
    port: 32777,
    path: '/wd/hub',
    logLevel: 'verbose'
};

const browser = webdriverio.remote(options);
browser.init()
.url('http://example.com')
.pause(2000)
.close()
.endAll();
```

can be run only once, if I stop it and restart it it just hangs.
is there anything I'm doing wrong?

This is how it runs the first time:

```
node test.js

[13:07:04]  COMMAND POST   "/wd/hub/session"
[13:07:04]  DATA    {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"browserName":"chrome","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"4.2.8","name":"webdriverio"}}}
[13:07:06]  INFO  SET SESSION ID f38cd279-6ab9-4aca-9a4a-c55592831eaa
[13:07:06]  RESULT    {"applicationCacheEnabled":false,"rotatable":false,"mobileEmulationEnabled":false,"networkConnectionEnabled":false,"chrome":{"chromedriverVersion":"2.24.417424 (c5c5ea873213ee72e3d0929b47482681555340c3)","userDataDir":"/tmp/.org.chromium.Chromium.j7Q8e3"},"takesHeapSnapshot":true,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","databaseEnabled":false,"handlesAlerts":true,"hasTouchScreen":true,"version":"54.0.2840.59","platform":"LINUX","browserConnectionEnabled":false,"nativeEvents":true,"acceptSslCerts":true,"webdriver.remote.sessionid":"f38cd279-6ab9-4aca-9a4a-c55592831eaa","locationContextEnabled":true,"webStorageEnabled":true,"browserName":"chrome","takesScreenshot":true,"javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true}
[13:07:06]  COMMAND POST   "/wd/hub/session/f38cd279-6ab9-4aca-9a4a-c55592831eaa/url"
[13:07:06]  DATA    {"url":"http://example.com"}
[13:07:07]  RESULT    null
[13:07:07]  COMMAND GET    "/wd/hub/session/f38cd279-6ab9-4aca-9a4a-c55592831eaa/title"
[13:07:07]  DATA    {}
[13:07:07]  RESULT    "Example Domain"
Example Domain
[13:07:09]  COMMAND GET    "/wd/hub/session/f38cd279-6ab9-4aca-9a4a-c55592831eaa/window_handles"
[13:07:09]  DATA    {}
[13:07:09]  RESULT    ["CDwindow-a5822994-4d02-4d05-b7d3-5e1f9e78bd4e"]
[13:07:09]  COMMAND DELETE   "/wd/hub/session/f38cd279-6ab9-4aca-9a4a-c55592831eaa/window"
[13:07:09]  DATA    {}
[13:07:09]  RESULT    null
[13:07:09]  COMMAND POST   "/wd/hub/session/f38cd279-6ab9-4aca-9a4a-c55592831eaa/window"
[13:07:09]  DATA    {"name":"CDwindow-a5822994-4d02-4d05-b7d3-5e1f9e78bd4e"}
```

and this is how it runs the second time

```
[13:17:59]  COMMAND POST   "/wd/hub/session"
[13:17:59]  DATA    {"desiredCapabilities":{"javascriptEnabled":true,"locationContextEnabled":true,"handlesAlerts":true,"rotatable":true,"browserName":"chrome","loggingPrefs":{"browser":"ALL","driver":"ALL"},"requestOrigins":{"url":"http://webdriver.io","version":"4.2.8","name":"webdriverio"}}}
[13:17:59]  COMMAND GET    "/wd/hub/sessions"
[13:17:59]  DATA    {}
^C
```

it seems that it is not able to SET SESSION ID

Comment: Can you the the command how you starting it? What is exact error that you get when it is started for next time?

Comment: I've added some debugging stuff into the root comment